# Some "train" columns aren't present in "test"

Tags: r

everyone.

I have a problem. I have to realize a kNN classification on R using LOO. I've found packages "knncat" and "loo" for this. And I've written the code(without LOO):

```
library(knncat)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
train <- data.frame(x, y)
x1 <- c(9, 10, 11, 12)
y1 <- c(13, 14, 15, 16)
test <- data.frame(x1, y1)
answer <- knncat(train, test, classcol = 2)
```

And I've got an error "Some "train" columns aren't present in "test"". I don't understand, what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

If something's wrong with my English, sorry, I'm from Russia:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are some problems with your approach and `knncat`:

1. You have to specify class labels for the `train` and `test` data sets and set `classcol` accordingly.
2. Only class labels which appear in train must be present in test.
3. The columns names of train and test must be the same, or knncat will throw the error you've mentioned: `"Some "train" columns aren't present in "test"`.
4. Moreover if you are using integer values as class labels, they have to start from **zero** or knncat will throw an error: `"Number in class 0 is 0! Abort!"`.

Here is an working example:

```
train <- data.frame(x1=1:4, x2=5:8, y=c(0, 0, 1, 1))
test <- data.frame(x1=9:12, x2=13:16, y=c(1, 0, 0, 1))
knncat(train, test, classcol = 3)
```

With the result:

```
Test set misclass rate: 50%
```

Comment: But can you explain, what does vector 'y' mean in "train" and "test"? I understand, that x1, x2 - attributes of cases. But what is vector 'y'?

Comment: `y` contains the class labels (the target variable, you want to predict) in these examples. The first two rows of the `train` data.frame belong to the class 0, the last two rows to class 1. Let's assume class 0 represents the case where a question on stackoverflow won't be answered and class 1 the case where a question will be answered and you want to predict if a question will be answered. Then you first have to use some training data to learn the knncat model and afterwards apply the model on new data. In the example above test data was provided to be able to calculate a classification rate.

Comment: I am trying to use knncat with categorical data but i keep receiving a "Sets of levels in train and test don't match", even when I pass the same dataframe both as test and train! how is this possible? In the public code of knncat I see that lapply (train[,-1], levels) is compared with sapply (test[,-1,drop=FALSE], levels) using are.equal. Even when I pass the same test and train, this condition is false and doesn't let me go on. How can I solve this?